# Insert Bulk Data in existing rows SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle's DB.I have a table say T. It has following columns id, att1,att2,att3. Now for a large amount of data att3 is blank. I've created a csv file which contains data in the format id,att3 it has a lot of data. How do I updatefrom this file to existing rows?
Any way of doing it via pl/SQL

Comment: You'll first have to bulk load it into a new table (which you can drop afterwards). You can perform the update from there.

Comment: Can you clean up your questions, are you asking to `INSERT` rows or are you asking to `UPDATE` your question describes updating but asks to insert.

Comment: I meant how to update the existing rows! Thanks updated the questions

Comment: @HoneyBadger Any pointers on how to do that?

Comment: 1: Create Table, 2: Bulk load csv data, 3: Update existing table, 4: Drop table created in step 1.

Comment: I don't have permissions to create a new table :( ! any alternatives??

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952714/update-oracle-table-with-values-from-csv-file)

Answer (score 0):

Which database engine are you using? The answer might vary depending on that.
But this post here [How to update selected rows with values from a CSV file in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910494/how-to-update-selected-rows-with-values-from-a-csv-file-in-postgres) is similar to what you're asking, I'm sure you can adapt it to your needs.